# AppScript. Is there a way to check if list item has a checkbox?

Tags: google-apps-script

Google document allows to add list items with a checkboxes, like on the screenshot below:
[image]

I need to write a appscript to check if list item has a checbox, but i haven't found appropriate field/method in documentation and this kind of list item return `null` instead of GlyphType:
[image]

Does anyone know if it is actually possible somehow?

Comment: Look for checkbox validations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### This isn't currently possible!

But there is already a report on Google's Issue Tracker which requests the behaviour you seek:

- [Add support for all glyph types in Docs (bullets and number formats)](https://issuetracker.google.com/36762366)

Google does seem to know about this feature request but if it's causing problems I suggest leaving a comment to bump its priority.

You can also hit the ☆ next to the issue number in the top left on the aforementioned pages which lets Google know more people would like to see this implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Log time of this question.

From Google, nothing relevant about this has changed, but I am working on a script when I need to check the glypth type too.
My strategy(a workaround) is simple and it is working: if ***elem.getGlyphType()*** is diferent to all ***DocumentApp.ElementType*** Enums, it returns null; so

```
if(elem.getGlyphType()==null){
    //it is a checkbox
}
```

Take care: When Google(a dream day) add a new enum type to checkboxes it didnt work

Maybe it helps someone.